# Path Traversal in Java

Tags: java, tree-traversal, dom-traversal

I have a list of Activities and a list of Activities and the Start Activity, which I am supposedly fetching by parsing an XML.

Now I need to find the Possible Paths from Start to End in Java.

I googled some algo's that could do the same but, Dijkstra requires a directed conencted graph(which we dont have) and others are search and traversal algo's.

Please help.

Comment: you may use JGraph in order to build the graph from the XML containing the data; then on the created graph you can use all the JGraph algorithms

Comment: This seems to display a graph, Let me rephrase, I do not wish to display the graph, just to use it internally to find all possible paths from source to Destination.Also request you to provide a link for your suggestion,that would be helpful!